# How to get specific strings from multiple memos

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to check specific strings from multiple memos and if all of them check out then run a procedure, but in my code sometimes the procedure runs and sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes it runs only when a few have checked out.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer14Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo10.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo10.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo9.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo9.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo8.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo8.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo7.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo7.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo6.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo6.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo5.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo5.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo4.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo4.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo3.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo3.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo2.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo2.text)<>0)
    and (pos('ActiveTunnel',memo1.Text)<>0) or (pos('https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor',memo1.text)<>0)
  then
  begin
    if Checkbox1.Checked = true then
    begin
      starttun;
      sleep(3000);
      routesaddlast;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: On a side-note, you should really get into the habit of naming your components. `Timer14` tells me you have at least 13 other timer components with no identifiable name.

Comment: On a side-note, you should really get into the habit of indenting. ... Re-entrancy  to timer handler is possible if message queue is pumped, does your "starttun" or "routeaddlast" have any Application.ProcessMessages?

Comment: The first linie of your timer event handler should be `Timer14.Enabled := False;` to prevent re-entrancy. (Do you seriously have 14 timers active at once? If so, you're most likely doing something very wrong.)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [this table](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence) you'll see that `and` has higher precedence than `or`. That means that the clauses in your code are in fact the equivalent of:

```pascal
if (pos(..., memo10.Text) <> 0) 
   or ((pos(..., memo10.Text) <> 0) and (pos(..., memo9.Text) <> 0))
   or ((pos(..., memo9.Text) <> 0) and (pos(..., memo8.Text) <> 0))
   or ((pos(..., memo8.Text) <> 0) and (pos(..., memo7.Text) <> 0))
   etc...
```

and that is why you get that **sometimes it works as expected and sometimes it doesn't**. I guess you actually want:

```
if ( (pos(..., memo10.Text) <> 0) or (pos(..., memo10.text) <> 0) ) and
   ( (pos(..., memo9.Text) <> 0) or (pos(..., memo9.text) <> 0) ) and
   ( (pos(..., memo8.Text) <> 0) or (pos(..., memo8.text) <> 0) ) and
   etc...
```

In other words, **add parentheses around the or-clauses** to give them higher precedence than *and*.

Note that, [so you don't have to repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you can do:

```
const 
  S0 = 'ActiveTunnel';
  S1 = 'https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor';

procedure TForm1.Timer14Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ((Pos(S0, memo10.Text) <> 0) or (Pos(S1, memo10.Text) <> 0)) and
     ((Pos(S0, memo9.Text) <> 0) or (Pos(S1, memo9.Text) <> 0)) and
  // etc...
```

and simplify this:

```
function FindIt(memo: TMemo): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Pos(S0, memo.Text) <> 0) or (Pos(S1, memo.Text) <> 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer14Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FindIt(memo10) and 
     FindIt(memo9) and 
     FindIt(memo8) // etc.
```

Of course you could also give *FindIt* an open array parameter and pass any number of strings, to make it more general.

Comment: where do i put this

`S0 := 'ActiveTunnel';
 S1 := 'https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor';`

Comment: Before you use them. Where exactly is up to you, but it must be in a code block. See my edit.